# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'dict'

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I got this error TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'builtin_function_or_method' when I try execute this line

> best_player = max(self.players_scores, self.players_scores.get)

.

Here is my code:

```py
class Yatzy:
    def __init__(self, humans_num, bots_num):(...)

    @property
    def players_scores(self):
        scores = {}
        for i in range(len(self.humans)):
            scores[self.humans[i].name] = self.humans[i].total_score
        for i in range(len(self.bots)):
            scores[self.bots[i].name] = self.bots[i].total_score
        print(type(self.bots[0].name), type(self.bots[0].total_score))
        return scores

    def game_loop(self):
        print('Welcome to Yatzy game!')
        round_counter = 1
        while round_counter <= self.MAX_ROUNDS:(...)
        print("Final score:", self.players_scores)
        print(type(self.players_scores), type(self.players_scores.keys()), type(self.players_scores.values()))
        best_player = max(self.players_scores, self.players_scores.get)
        print("{} won with {}".format(best_player, self.players_scores[best_player]))

game = Yatzy(humans_num=0, bots_num=4)
game.game_loop()
```

Here is the output of my prints:

```
Key type: <class 'str'> Value type: <class 'int'>
Final score: {'Bot1': 112, 'Bot2': 110, 'Bot3': 81, 'Bot4': 79}
Key type: <class 'str'> Value type: <class 'int'>
Key type: <class 'str'> Value type: <class 'int'>
Key type: <class 'str'> Value type: <class 'int'>
<class 'dict'> <class 'dict_keys'> <class 'dict_values'>
Key type: <class 'str'> Value type: <class 'int'>
Key type: <class 'str'> Value type: <class 'int'>

    > Traceback (most recent call last):  
 File
    > "C:/Users/Artur/Desktop/Python/yatzy/yatzy.py", line 140, in <module>
    >     game.game_loop()  
 File "C:/Users/Artur/Desktop/Python/yatzy/yatzy.py", line 135, in game_loop
    >     best_player = max(self.players_scores, self.players_scores.get)
 TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of
    > 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'dict'
```

Comment: You have to call methods if they are not a `property`.

Comment: Ehh I forgot to write key=self.players_scores.get

Comment: `player_scores` is a `@property`, and as such you don't have to call `get` on it, because there's no such method on it...

Comment: @ArturOwczarek If you forgot to add something to your question - edit the question, don't add it in a comment.

Comment: The key function needs to be passed by keyword, `key=self.players_scores.get`. There's a duplicate around here somewhere...

Comment: I mean in line `best_player = max(self.players_scores, self.players_scores.get)` should be `best_player = max(self.players_scores, key=self.players_scores.get)`. Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

The arguments to `max` need to be numbers - or, very specifically, as indicated by the error message you got, need to support greater-than comparison against each other (by way of implementing Python's `__gt__` method). If you pass in objects which do not satisfy this condition, you get an error.

In this specific case, it looks like you forgot to identify the second argument as a keyword argument.

```py
best_player = max(self.players_scores, key=self.players_scores.get)
```

`max` is also slightly peculiar in that it accepts either a list (as you apparently intended) or simply a sequence of non-keyword arguments to compare as a list.